# Monero mining equipments can mine Zcash as well and have the same hashpower?

Tags: mining, mining-theory, mining-hardware, zcash

Is any device capable to mine monero, also capable to mine Zcash (zec)? The hashes per second offered in that equipment for monero would apply also for zcash?

That would be helpful for the mining calculations I want to do, because I want to be able to switch between both coins during my mining operations.

Answer (score 2):

No. Monero uses Cryptonight whereas Zcash uses Equihash. They are different algorithms and most devices will compute them at different speeds, though for some devices they may happen to be close.

Answer (score 1):

Any hardware that is capable of mining Monero can also mine Zcash. But the used algorithm is different so you will need a different software. If you are using a pool it most likely doesn't make any difference. You just switch the mining URL.

Another thing is that the two coins are at different difficulties because they are not the same age (and also because of the used algorithm).

Zcash is easier to mine. A good new pool is for example [coinfoundry.org](https://coinfoundry.org)

Comment: Should be noted Zcash pools are currently unbalanced and would be advised to not mine on flypool as it currently (28/02/2018) has over 50% of the hashrate.